# Paypal add to cart button html for handling_cart options

Tags: html, paypal

I am OK at html but new to PayPal.
I want to be able to use a Paypal button directly from my site without having to use a third party shopping cart.

The only problem I have is that I am in the UK and Paypal do not offer postage/shipping options here dependent on where you are shipping to. So for instance PayPal's standard buttons would not allow me to charge different postage whether I was sending the product to the US or just a nearby town.

They allow you to add postage/shipping dependent on the value of the cart only.

So I have been looking at the html variables available for the buttons here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HH0D0TA and at posts on Stackoverflow

I wondered if there was any way of combining the option value.. and ="handling_cart" to do this – please see my working below.

So you would click the add to cart button and from the drop down select the shipping area e.g. UK, Europe, Rest of World. The handling charge on the cart would then reflect the option you chose. Instead of the handling cart value being NNNN it would be the value specified for the option, so for Europe £5.00.

```html
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="DLNKFJWJGHZFW">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Shipping Options">Shipping Options</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
 <option value="UK Second Class  + £2.85">UK Second Class  + £2.85 £2.85 GBP</option>
 <option value="UK First Class + £3.85">UK First Class + £3.85 £3.85 GBP</option>
 <option value="Europe + £5.00">Europe + £5.00 £5.00 GBP</option>
 <option value="Rest of World + £7.00">Rest of World + £7.00 £7.00 GBP</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="or call us on +44(0)444444444">or call us on +44(0)444444444</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="NNNN">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Secondary question:  this html gets a straight error from PayPal, probably – among other things -  because I am still calling it a hosted button (I think I might need to remove this and somehow link it to the Merchant ID???).

Note I have altered the hosted button id here as I was concerned about security - I might not need to be.

Many Thanks

Allyson

Comment: This is my first question on Stackoverflow. I wondered why it has -1 votes. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you asked multiple questions and it doesn't show that you make any effort to resolve the problem, looks like you are using javascript to handle the cart but there is no javascript in your question also it's too broad, that's my review of your question, so someone else also did the review and downvoted it

Comment: all the problems you mentioned in your question already been addressed here on SO, you have to dig deep and Paypal is no rocket science, they have very detailed documentation, just read those documents carefully and you will find all answers there too

Comment: Don't agree - I have searched widely in Stackoverflow onhow to add postage options for the UK - there is no solution and I tried to move it forward by wondering in you could use the options combined with the Handling cart. The form cgi_bin reference is direct from Paypal - I use none of my own javascript. I apologies for asking a secondary question. It is my first ever post.

Comment: it's not necessary that someone asked the question `how to add postage options for the uk` but someone did ask this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908348/paypal-express-checkout-adding-postage-options-dependent-on-location

Comment: and if I google `how to add postage options in paypal uk`, i found this on paypal community site https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/Adding-international-postage-rates-as-well-as-UK-ones-to-my/td-p/168086/page/2

Comment: How about this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487870/international-shipping-calculation-with-paypal and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31358450/paypal-buy-now-shopping-cart-with-and-without-postage-assistance and may be this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784100/i-need-to-create-a-custom-postage-price-depending-on-quantity-ordered-for-paypal

Comment: Yes I read through all that a few days ago - if you read it there is no solution given. I have also rang Paypal here in the UK and they told me that there is no solution using the auto buttons but I might find one in the developers help. So I did search thru that - hence the link I used to teh html variables.. The other link you give is about using the Callback API. I really wanted to avoid this as I currently do not have very good script skills and it would mean learning a hec of a lot - which I would love to do but I need to get the payment buttons on.

Comment: Just for a sec forget all the information you read and what paypal said, a logical question, how you will handle the order if (just assume that what you asked in question resolved) a customer placed an order and payment gets through via paypal? Where you are managing the order information?

Comment: Hello - sorry I had to pop out for an appointment - re order management  the orders will typically be for one or two books to do with a long distance walk near here. The site is run by a very small local bookshop  and we have agreed the paypal email notification we are sent will be enough.

Comment: so you have no check and balance at website end for order information, and after reading your comment i assume the postal charges are also static, not from database?

Comment: Ref the  "check and balance" that you refer to - we are just planning to have PayPal add to cart buttons. There are only about 20 products in total. The postal charges are a choice depending on the location: UK (ideally two choices first and second class - but we can manage just offering second class), Europe and rest of world.

Comment: it will be a very long discussion, making it short without IPN or `Callback API` what you are trying to achieve may not be easily possible and you have to manage the prices at your website end postal charges etc before redirecting the customer to paypal, it will be your website that does the heavy lifting not paypal and the check and balance means to make sure that if an order placed no one able to manipulate the prices and charges, with what you are trying to do it's very easy to manipulate the postal charges and prices before redirecting to paypal,

Comment: Yes they could choose a cheaper delivery option. Looking at various forums that is how people have had to go ahead and do it  - . They have set up a buy now and a drop down so people pick there own price based on their location. I was trying to take this on so that you could  at least have a shopping cart. The PayPal shipping to different regions is only available in the US and this is confusing when you google - it looks like its easy but it isn't easy outside the US!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosted button is not formatted correctly to handle the shipping drop down. Also you cannot modify a hosted button it will not work. I have created some sample non-hosted button code as an example of what will work if the shipping calculator is not available in your region.  
You will have to update the business value to reflect your merchant id or your email address to test the button code.

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="youremail@email.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Shipping Options">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller:">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<table>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Shipping Options">Shipping Options</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="UK Second Class">UK Second Class £2.85 GBP</option>
    <option value="UK First Class">UK First Class £3.85 GBP</option>
    <option value="Europe">Europe £5.00 GBP</option>
    <option value="Rest of World">Rest of World £7.00 GBP</option>
</select> </td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on1" value="or call us on +44(0)444444444">or call us on +44(0)444444444</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os1" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select0" value="UK Second Class">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount0" value="2.85">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select1" value="UK First Class">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount1" value="3.85">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select2" value="Europe">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount2" value="5.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_select3" value="Rest of World">
<input type="hidden" name="option_amount3" value="7.00">
<input type="hidden" name="option_index" value="0">


<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: THANKS! I have tried this out. This is a real step forward! Just to check my understanding: - I would have to add two buttons to every product, one to add the Book/Map being sold and another to choose the shipping option?

Comment: If you do not have the shipping calculator option in your region, then yes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No we don't and even Canada doesn't apparently. Come on Paypal - why not! :-) :-)